# Unable to install GUI on Ubuntu

Tags: gui, vps, putty

I just bought a VPS and I have it in running using puTTY. Now I want to install GUI in Ubuntu but I am unable to do so. I have followed many tutorials but at the end they write “sudo reboot” in their terminal and their server restarts and they are greeted with the UI but in my case as soon as I run sudo reboot my terminal becomes unresponsive and puTTY stops. I have tried this for both version 18.04 LTS & 20.04 LTS of Ubuntu but the same thing happens again and again.

Comment: `sudo reboot` will kill any `ssh` session as the machine reboots. Ubuntu server & desktop releases are *yy.mm* in format, so do you mean those versions? or are you talking about Ubuntu Core (appliance releases which are *snap* based and use *yy* format?) Providing the set of instructions (or link to them) may also help.

Comment: Actually I am using a Ubuntu on a VPS but I am not sure what the tutorials are following as I am new to this field.

Comment: Its just that I want to use GUI on my Ubuntu VPS. It would be great if you suggest something.

Comment: I am talking about Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS and Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Can you please help me solve this problem?

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: First of all, you can't use GUI when connecting via ssh. This service is for console mode only. You have to use some other service to connect to your VPS, that can transfer a graphics display, for example VNC. Find some tutorials how to set up a VNC server on Ubuntu and try this.

Comment: okay let me try

Comment: I solved the problem by connecting the server using Remote Desktop Connection.Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please write how you solved it as an answer, then after a period of time (to allow others to write alternative answers) you can accept your answer as accepted (unless you like any alternatives better).  When accepted, you'll gain REP for this & in time other SE sites.  (otherwise this you risk getting this closed as *problem that went away* without any rep achieved)

Comment: Okay and can you help me with this question please.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266514/user-is-not-in-the-subdoers-file-the-incident-will-be-reported